# u-boot environement writing is always enabled regardless of force_ro value

Tags: u-boot, nxp-microcontroller, yocto-kirkstone

On my platform, the u-boot environment variables can always be modified. Currently, I'm changing the value of `force_ro` to '1', which sets the permission mode to read-only. This change is reflected in the output of the `lsblk` command. However, even after rebooting my device, I can still write values to my boot partition, and the changes persist.

Here are the results of my test:

```
$ cat /sys/block/mmcblk0boot1/force_ro
1
$ fw_setenv primary 2
$ fw_printenv primary
2
```

Here are some details about my platform:

- Cross Compiler: Yocto EL40(Kirkstone)
- Bootloader: u-boot
- U-boot Source: git://github.com/nxp-imx/uboot-imx.git;protocol=https
- U-boot Source Branch: lf_v2022.04
- `fw_setenv` and `fw_printenv` package version in Yocto: libubootenv_0.3.2

Hardware details:

- System Architecture: arm
- CPU: armv8
- SoC: imx8m

Could anyone suggest a solution to make my boot partition read-only based on the value of `force_ro`?

I checked all the u-boot configuration, attempted multiple tests

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: You could better explain the situation by first mentioning that the operational environment is Linux. You provide some (mostly irrelevant or redundant) details, but not enough salient specifics (e.g. any U-Boot configuration, a specific board) to replicate or identify the problem. Where is the U-Boot environment actually stored? What are the contents of the **/etc/fw_env.config** file? IOW are you enforcing protection on the correct partition (or file or raw sectors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue reason was the **libubootenv** commit: https://github.com/sbabic/libubootenv/commit/92949816720d7af2ac722016e7a5b9a85ff141bc. which bypasses the force_ro protection to write.
So for my platform, I am going to edit the source code of  libubootenv

- And about the last replay of this thread, Yes I am sure that the environment variables are stored on `/dev/mmcblk0boot1` as [`dd if=/xx/<uboot>.img of=/dev/mmcblk0boot1 conv=notrunc seek=xx bs=1k`]
- `cat /etc/fw_env.config` has the entry as `/dev/mmcblk0boot1            xx xx`
- strac command of fw_setenv showing as `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mmcblk0boot1",enter code here`

Anyway, the issue's root cause was found and resolved.

Thanks